LUKS decryption of root disk during boot with key over wifi
The setup is a laptop connected to my local network via wifi, and a tang server in the same network providing decryption keys.
The laptop runs Ubuntu 22.04 and has its root disk encrypted with LUKS. Decryption should be automatic when in the local network. For this I successfully used clevis and clevis-initramfs to ask the tang server for a key. However this works only via LAN cable, not via WiFi.
Is there any possibility to enable WiFi access during boot for the clevis client? All docs and answers that I find are RedHat/Fedora/dracut specific.

I tried this sometime ago but couldn't get Wi-Fi working before booting Ubuntu. It works with Ethernet.

Thanks! Yes, that‘s exactly my problem at the moment. However, the laptop is usually not plugged in.

Other options are to 1. USB unlock., or 2. buy ans set up a YubiKey..
